# How read a sms from android

Tags: android

I try to make a simple app for read sms from my smartphone,
I run the code but and but anythings shows in my application
I try to debug the code I found this variable cur cannot be found

what is the problem here ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private static final int request_permission = 123;
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void ButtonLoad(View view) {

      if((int) Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23){

         if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            if(!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)){


                requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},request_permission);
            }

            return;
      }
    }
    LoadInboxMassges();

}

  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){

        case request_permission:
            if (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){


                LoadInboxMassges();

            }else {


                //permission_Denied

            }





    }
}



void LoadInboxMassges(){

    try {
        String sms = "";
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null,null, null, null);
        cur.moveToPosition(0);
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {

            sms += "From : " + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("adress")) + " : " + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body")) + "\n";


            TextView txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv);


            txtDisplay.setText(sms);


        }
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 remove this line `cur.moveToPosition(0);`

2 Change the word `"adress"` of this line:

```
sms += "From : " + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("adress")) + " : " + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body")) + "\n";
```

to `"address"`.

**Other suggestions:**

There are some other errors or something improper in your code, such as:

> 1 Reading sms in your inbox may spend a **long time**. That may crash your app.
>
> 2 Your `txtDisplay` should be placed **out of the loop body**.
>
> 3 You should call `cur.close();` after cur is in the end.

Comment: Why you did not accept my answer? you said it worked for you.

Comment: sorry,I thought I could choose two answers
Thank uuuu

Answer (score 0):

1. In your LoadInboxMassges() method
2. remove the code cur.moveToPosition(0);
3. change in the following manner

   ```
    if (cursor != null) {

       while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
           // read your cursor here
       }
   ```

Comment: Thank u Sir for your suggestion